Why isn't `fromDouble` a method of `Num`?
Say I have Pair defined as
data Pair num = Pair num num

and Pair implements Num as one would usually do.
instance (Num num) => Num (Pair num) where
  (Pair x1 y1) + (Pair x2 y2) = Pair (x1 + x2) (y1 + y2)
  fromInteger i = Pair i i
  ...

This works if a Pair is added with an int, e.g.
10 + (Pair 1.0 42)

But when added to a Double, the type checker becomes annoyed.
10.0 + (Pair 1.0 42)

No instance for (Fractional (Pair Double))
    arising from the literal ‘10.0’

I imagine that + only works on identical types (as suggested in a -> a -> a), but it may cut a slack and invoke fromInteger when it expects an a but got an int.
My question is why Double isn't treated the same way (or maybe fromIntegral)? How can we make 10.0 + (pair 1.0 42) type check?

"it may cut a slack and invoke fromInteger when it expects an a but got an int." - no, this is not +, this is Haskell itself overloading integral literals. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73935193/clarifying-numeric-literal-definition-in-haskell

"and Pair implements Num as one would usually do"
It's somewhat questionable if one would normally implement Num for pairs. There's a reason that's not what base does.

Integer literals like 10 require a Num instance for the target type, while float literals like 10.0 require a Fractional instance.
In both your expressions, you are trying to use these literals 10 and 10.0 as Point Double types.  With a Num instance for Point Double, this will work for 10.  To get it to work with 10.0, you need a similar Fractional instance for Point Double.
The following example should work:
instance (Num num) => Num (Pair num) where
  Pair x1 y1 + Pair x2 y2 = Pair (x1 + x2) (y1 + y2)
  fromInteger i = let i' = fromInteger i in Pair i' i'

instance (Fractional num) => Fractional (Pair num) where
  fromRational i = let i' = fromRational i in Pair i' i'

main = do
  print $ 10 + Pair 1.0 42
  print $ 10.0 + Pair 1.0 42


In 10 + (Pair 1.0 42), it's not that + decide's to "cut you some slack" and invoke fromInteger if it's given an integer. + never sees the integer 10! + is just adding two Pairs; what's actually going on is that 10 is a literal for the data structure Pair 10 10, in exactly the same way that "abc" is a literal for the data structure 'a' : 'b' : 'c' : []. You're not adding an int and a pair, you're simply adding pairs; it's just that the way you wrote down one of the pairs was using the source code text 10.
A literal is just way of writing a value down as source code; they do not correspond to how the value they represent will actually be stored in the computer at runtime. Even for machine-word integers, the literals are sequences of ASCII digit characters, not a fixed-width chunk of bits.
When you have defined a Num instance, the source code text 10 is a way of writing a literal value for Pair 10 10. The fromIntegral part of the Num class is used as a "hook" for you to instruct the compiler how it should handle integers in the source code to specify values of type Pair a. But this hook specifically handles integer literals. Not literals with a decimal point like 10.01
Don't confuse the integer literals that Num handles with the resulting type, which may not be any sort of integer. 10 as an integer literal can be used to specify a Double value, by using fromInteger at the type Integer -> Double. But when you write 10.5 in the source code, fromInteger :: Integer -> Double isn't going to help! Instead the compiler recognises the syntax of a fractional literal and calls fromRational from the Fractional class, using the type fromRational :: Rational -> Double. This decision is based on the syntactic form of the literal (that it has a decimal point), so 10.0 is treated the same way even though there are only zeroes after the decimal point.
So likewise the literal source code 10.0 used to specify a Pair Double will want to use fromRational as Rational -> Pair Double. This means the compiler needs a Fractional instance for Pair Double (or Pair a), and has to abort when it doesn't find one. And that's exactly what the error message told you.

1 Nor string literals nor list literals, which all have their own class that can be used to tell the compiler how to use the literal syntax to specify values of custom types.
